# instance variable same type as?

Tags: java, generics

Consider this Converter interface:

```
public interface Converter<T1, T2>
{
public T2 convert(T1 toConvert);

public T1 reverseConvert(T2 toReverseConvert);
}
```

If I now have an abstract class which takes the converter interface as a generic argument:

```
public abstract ConverterContainer<T extends Converter<?,?>>{
    protected final T converter;
    protected final T1 converterT1; //inherit converter T1
    protected final T2 converterT2; //inherit converter T2

}
```

I want to be able to inherit the types from converter without having to declare the generic types in ConverterContainer.

Comment: This is just a simple example. Please ignore the fact that Integer does not have an no arg constructor. Let.s pretend that for now it does. @kayaman

Comment: When your example is so "simple" that it makes no logical sense, it is no longer "simple".

Comment: That still doesn't change the fact that in your code you don't need to care about `T1` and `T2`, and dynamically creating instances of them is just crazy. To the example code I would suggest "remove everything, it's bad and unnecessary". So, not a very good example if you intend to get help. Also, don't fall into [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), thinking that your solution is the best approach.

Comment: I don't see any advantage in a `StringIntegerConverterContainer` over `ConverterContainer<StringIntegerConverter>`, so you seem to be introducing an additional layer of inheritance for no real reason. Still you don't need to access `T1` or `T2`, so what you have is a design problem and a bad solution you're trying to force through. Maybe you shouldn't try to make so many named classes that extend a generic class? Just use the generic classes directly instead?

Comment: I hope my latest edit simplifies the problem.

Comment: As far as I've seen, you don't have a problem. I don't see any reason why you would need to create new objects based on the type parameters, and I still don't see where `T1` and `T2` would be used. If you want a real solution, post your real problem.

Comment: "without having to declare the generic types in ConverterContainer."  Why not? Generics only happen at compile time, based on declared types. If you don't declare types, you won't get much benefit from them.

Comment: @thilo because T1 & t2 have already been declared by implementing Converter interface.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `public abstract ConverterContainer<T1, T2, T extends Converter<T1,T2>>` ? Because otherwise T1 and T2 will *not* have been declared there.

Comment: Thanks Thilo will give it a try.

Comment: @Thilo that solution works thanks. Do you want to post your comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to inherit the types from converter without having to declare the generic types in ConverterContainer.

You will have to declare all generic types for both the derived class and the parent class, but you can bind them together:

```
public abstract ConverterContainer<T1, T2, T extends Converter<T1, T2>>
       extends Converter<T1,T2>
```

So here you have on your new class

- the types `T1` and `T2` with the exact meaning as in the parent class (but you could have changed their names, if you wanted, all that matters is where they appear in the `extends` clause)
- an extra type `T` that in this case is constrained to be a `Converter<T1, T2>`, but could be something completely different as well